# Ionic redirect from HttpInterceptor

Tags: ionic-framework, service, ionic2

I recently upgraded to Angular 4 and would like to be able to redirect a user from within a service if they have a `401` response.  I cannot inject `NavController`, or `Nav` so I am having trouble making it work.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(public auth: AuthProvider, private global: GlobalVariablesProvider) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log("401 working")

    return next.handle(request).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
      if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {

      }
    }, (err: any) => {
      console.log(err)
      if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        console.log(err)
        if (err.status === 401) {
          this.global.handleResponse("Unathorized attempt.  Redirecting to login")

          // Perform redirect
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I think I need to access the global `nav` but I am unsure how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to import `App` and call `getRootNav()`:

```
import { App } from "ionic-angular"

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(public auth: AuthProvider, public app: App, private global: GlobalVariablesProvider) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    return next.handle(request).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
      if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {

      }
    }, (err: any) => {
      console.log(err)
      if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        console.log(err)
        if (err.status === 401) {
          this.global.handleResponse("Unauthorized attempt.  Redirecting to login")
          this.app.getRootNav().setRoot(LoginPage)
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```